# Parse e-mail addresses with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, email

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098581/how-to-parse-trim-email-addresses-from-text), how could I parse e-mail addresses which are in this format,

```
"Bob Smith" <bob@company.com>, joe@company.com, "John Doe"<john@company.com>
```

And get the a result like this:

```
array(
    'bob@company.com'=>'Bob Smith'
    'joe@company.com'=>''
    'john@company.com'=>'John Doe'
);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse RFC 822 compliant addresses in a TO header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609195/parse-rfc-822-compliant-addresses-in-a-to-header)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, you could use [`mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses()`](http://php.net/mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses), which does exactly that. It's a PECL extension, so it might be easier to use [`Mail_RFC822::parseAddressList()`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.php) as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 8):

This should work with just about anything:

```
$str = '"Bob Smith" <bob@company.com>, joe@company.com, "John Doe"<john@company.com>, Billy Doe<billy@company.com>';
$emails = array();

if(preg_match_all('/\s*"?([^><,"]+)"?\s*((?:<[^><,]+>)?)\s*/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) > 0)
{
    foreach($matches as $m)
    {
        if(! empty($m[2]))
        {
            $emails[trim($m[2], '<>')] = $m[1];
        }
        else
        {
            $emails[$m[1]] = '';
        }
    }
}

print_r($emails);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [bob@company.com] => Bob Smith
    [joe@company.com] => 
    [john@company.com] => John Doe
    [billy@company.com] => Billy Doe
)
```

Comment: I like the simplicity, but it doesn't handle commas in the name part, like '"Smith, Bob" <bob@example.com>'

Answer (score 1):

This is a fully working piece of code below that even validates whether the email is correct or not ;)

```
<?php
$mails = '"Bob Smith" <bob@company.com>, joe@company.com, "John Doe"<john@company.com>';

$records = explode(",",$mails);

foreach($records as $r){
  preg_match("#\"([\w\s]+)\"#",$r,$matches_1);
  $name = $matches_1[1];


  preg_match("/[^0-9<][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}/i",$r,$matches_2);
  $email = $matches_2[0];

  echo "Name: $name <br /> Email: $email <br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: `[A-z]` includes the following symbols: `[`, `\`,  `]`, `^`, `_`,  and the back tick. You do not mean to include these.

Comment: Escaping slashes before double quotes in the pattern can be avoided by declaring the pattern inside a single-quoted string. `@` does not have a special meaning to the regex engine and does not need to be explicitly written as a literal via braces.  `[0-9A-Za-z_]` is more simply written as `\w`. Rather than splitting then calling pairs of regex calls in a loop, just call `preg_match_all()` once and iterate that payload.

Answer (score 1):

For a similar task I've used the following regex:

```
\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|([^,""<>]*))?\s*(?:(?:,|<|\s+|^)([^<@\s,]+@[^>@\s,]+)>?)\s*
```

https://regex101.com/r/Lpsjmr/1

PHP code:

```
$str = '"Bob Smith" <bob@company.com>, joe@company.com, "John Doe"<john@company.com>, Billy Doe<billy@company.com>';
if (preg_match_all('/\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|([^,""<>]*))?\s*(?:(?:,|<|\s+|^)([^<@\s,]+@[^>@\s,]+)>?)\s*/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) > 0) {
    $matches = array_map(function($x) { return [$x[1] . $x[2], $x[3]]; }, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: Why does the negated character class include the double quote twice?

Answer (score 0):

1. Explode the string by comma
2. If valid email then store it, if NO

   1. rtrim the '>' character
   2. explode by '<'
   3. trim the string for ('"', and ' ')

Comment: I wanted to say this wont work. But I think it will work fine!  Starts coding.

Comment: This doesnt work so well if you want to get the name & email. As a name could be "Ballinger, John <john@example.com>, email 2" but for purely getting emails, its not bad. (I want name and email and cannot install the PHP extension.)

Answer (score 0):

For input strings that are not properly parsed by the native function in @mario's answer, parse the substrings between delimiting commas using "branch resets" (`(?|...)`) and capture groups (`(...)`).

The branch reset ensure that (optionally occurring) names are always stored in column `1` of the matches array and that emails are always stored in column `2`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/avNaR))

```
$emails = '"Bob Smith" <bob@company.com>, joe@company.com, "John Doe"<john@company.com>, Billy Doe<billy@company.com>';

preg_match_all('/(?|(?|"([^"]+)"|([^<@]+)) ?<(.+?)>|()(.+?))(?:$|, ?)/', $emails, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_export(
    array_column($matches, 1, 2)
);
```